# How to add new build step feature to Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This is the first time I contribute to Jenkins code. I would like to add a new build step option to Jenkins (Like the "Execute shell" or "Invoke Ant" options). Where are these build steps kept? In the Jenkins core or is there a plugin that manages them?

Any tips on how to add a new build step capability to Jenkins and where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add a new step by modifying your Jenkinsfile. Any Jenkins tutorial should cover this (although admittedly most of them aren't very good).

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I think that's not what Aminov wants...

Comment: @StephenKing I see. I'm pretty inexperienced with Jenkins; I've only used it once. Your answer should be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

All pipeline steps are contributed by plugins, many by the `pipeline-*` or `workflow-*` plugins, but also by others.

[This](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/25/update-plugin-for-pipeline/) article should give you some guidance, how to add own steps in your plugin by extending `AbstractStepImpl`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am exploring it now and it seems very relevant to what I'm looking for. However my interest is in adding the new functionality to Jenkins in general and not to Pipeline projects only. The article seems to focus only on the latter. Anyway I will delve further into it. Thanks again!